# jenkins-docker cannot set the cloud credentials

Tags: rancher, jenkins-docker

I am trying to set up the jenkins-docker plugin to run using a Rancher system. To start a docker container requires using the rancher api and a username/password authentication.

In the "Jenkins Configuration" page under the "cloud" section, there is a options dialog that allows you to select which credentials to use. However the contents of the drop down only contain the value -none-.

I have defined the required credentials, and have added the 'Docker Commons Plugin' but I cannot get the drop down populated.

When I try and test the connection by pressing the "Test Connection" I get the following JSON response displayed.

{"id":"74519136-000d-4da0-b349-0219b7eb8987","type":"error","links":{},"actions":{},"status":401,"code":"Unauthorized","message":"Unauthorized","detail":null}

Does the jenkins-plugin support Rancher?
Am I using to correctly?

thanks
Richard

Comment: did you find a solution to the above. i am also facing the same issue. please share if there is a solution.